# На сайте непонятный баг с версткой

Tags: html, css

На сайте 
http://sisters.city/ 
при просмотре с телефонов Samsung вылазит баг с кнопкой входа в личный кабинет. Текст на ней смещается вниз а нужно по центру как по вертикали так и по горизонтали.

Comment: А это ваш сайт?

Comment: да это мой сайт

Comment: можно скриншот ошибки?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ojwbwr

Comment: Установите для кнопки display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте отцентрировать текст за счет `display: flex`

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: #f9ce8c;
  width: 76px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Вход</a>
```

Comment: Все работает проблема была в  line-height